# What is the current latest version of Apple's Books app for macOS?

Tags: macos, books

In the Books app on my Mac, About Books reports the version as **version 1.16**. Is this the current latest version?

I am running macOS 10.14. Wikipedia article for Apple Books mentions version 4.1 of iBooks for iOS.

Comment: Can you go to Apple menu → About This Mac and state the exact version of macOS Mojave that you are running? It could be of the form 10.14 or 10.14.x.

Comment: The version of Books app will depend on version of macOS that you are running. If you are not running the current latest version o f macOS, the version of Books app could be outdated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have v1.19, but I'm on a beta 10.14.5, so I don't know whether that's the generally-available 'latest'.

Note, though, that iOS & macOS versions are not necessarily ever in sync.

Answer (score 0):

The version of macOS Books I have is 1.18(1642). macOS Mojave 10.14.4